# How may I curtail or minimize the text below CKEditor (while keeping it available for screen readers)?

Tags: wysiwyg

In the add/edit form of a node, is there a way to reduce, hide, or minimize the **Text Format** block information contained inside of `<div class="form-item form-type-textarea form-item-body-und-0-value">`?

Would it be best to do an accessible hide as mentioned in [Drupal 7, two new system classes to improve accessibility](http://zufelt.ca/blog/drupal-7-two-new-system-classes-improve-accessibility) by using the classes `.element-invisible` and `.element-invisible.element-focusable`? Or should I edit a template file?

I'm using the [Autoform Block](https://drupal.org/project/afb) module and placing this block inside the main page of an Organic Group. The rich text editor is managed by using the [CKEditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) module.

[image: Text format dialog]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want something interactive, you can do this - this example assumes a field called `body` working on a node of type `article`, adjust as necessary:

- in css, for `.page-node-add-article .field-name-body .filter-wrapper .fieldset-wrapper { display:none; }` - this will initially hide the text format
- add this JS either in a custom module or in html.tpl.php before `</body>`, so long as it runs after ckeditor, or the classes won't exist and throw an error:

  ```
  <script>
      Drupal.behaviors.ckeditor_fix = {
          attach: function (context, settings)
          {
              jQuery('.page-node-add-article .field-name-body .filter-wrapper').once(function()
              {
                  jQuery(this).append('<div id="filter_show" style="width:100%; background:#ccc; text-align:center; cursor:pointer;">show/hide format information</div>');

                  jQuery('#filter_show').click(function()
                  {
                      jQuery('.page-node-add-article .field-name-body .filter-wrapper .fieldset-wrapper').slideToggle();
                  });
              });
          }
      };
  </script>
  ```

Comment: Up vote for sure. After fighting with it long enough, I've just surrendered to using CPN. That keeps designers in the admin UI and out of core SCSS files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm happy to tick the correct marker for any better answer, but for the meantime I'm using [Code Per Node](https://drupal.org/project/cpn) and the following

```
.block-afb fieldset {
positi/on: absolute !important;
clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 */
clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
}

.block-afb {
border: 1px solid blue;
background-color: #79A9D4;
margin: 5px; 
padding: 5px; 
width: 90%;
}
```

Comment: To avoid Code Per Node, you could add a class to the content type template, then put the css in your theme.